# C++ How to add numbers in an array within a given range?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on an assignment for class and am having a bit of a hard time putting it together. I had just started learning arrays and am not sure exactly how to get user input in the array.

Here is the assignment prompt: Create a program that inputs up to 100 integers (space separated!) and outputs their sum. For example:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
55

This is what I have so far (edit because I forgot to change comments):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addNum(int n);

int main() {
   int n;

   // prompt user to input numbers
   cout << "Please enter in values to add together: ";
   cin >> n;

   cout << addNum(n);

   // pause and exit
   getchar();
   getchar();
   return 0;
}

// function
int addNum(int n) {
   int arr[99] = {};
   int sum = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      sum = sum + arr[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: If your array needs to store up to 100 elements why do you set the size to 99 (`int arr[99] = {};`)?

Comment: `// declaration of a new array` says your comment, but you aren't declaring any array there at all. Also where is the user supposed to input anything into the array?

Comment: I thought that since the arrays start at 0 then going to 99 would make it 100 elements?

Comment: The number in the brackets when you declare the arrays is the size, not the last valid index. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The `arr[]` is created inside `addNum()` which means it's deleted when the function returns, all previous values are lost. Declare it outside the func.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` -- This loop is not safe in that you do not check if `n` exceeds the highest valid index of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a learning exercise, I wouldn't correct your code, but explain what you've missed so far:

- The assignment asks to read integers until there's no more input; your code prompts the user for the count upfront, which should be removed.
- You do not need an array to store the individual numbers, because the assignment asks only for the total. This can be computed on the fly: read a number, add it to `sum`, and forget the number.
- You can read numbers until the end of input with a simple loop that uses `>>` operator below.

Here is an example that limits the input to 100 numbers, or stops when the input stream ends:

```
int limit = 0;
int nextNumber;
while ((limit++ != 100) && (cin >> nextNumber)) {
    ... // Process the next number
}
```

If you are giving your program input from console (as opposed to feeding it a file with numbers) and you need to end your input sequence, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide a diverse range of answers, `std::accumulate` is pretty cool.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

```
int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

or in your case

```
int sum = std::accumulate(arr, arr + 99, 0);
```

Another functional approach is to use `std::reduce` introduced in C++17

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get a working code after talking to the professor about it! Here's the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // variable declarations
    int sum = 0, count = 0;
    int c;

    // array declaration
    int arr[100] = { 0 };

    // prompt user to input numbers & add
    cout << "Please enter in values to add together: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
        c = cin.peek();
        sum = sum + arr[i];

        // if user presses enter, skip to outputting sum without waiting for 100 values
        if (c == '\n'){
            break;
        }
    }

    // output the sum of input
    cout << sum;

    // pause and exit
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```